# WCF can't get object from other project in the same solution

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two projects in a solution:
Project A have defined some classes.
Project B is a WCF project and return object from project A

In project A, I write a function to get a list of objects (Song)

```
public class SongRepository
{
    private dbContext db = new dbContext();

    public List<Song> getAll()
    {
        List<Song> songs = db.Songs.ToList();
        return songs;
    }
}
```

An in project B, I write a function that used SongRepository to get a list of objects (Song)

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private SongRepository sr = new SongRepository();

    public List<Song> getAllSong()
    {

        List<Song> songs = sr.getAll();
        return songs;
    }
}
```

and IService1 class:

```
namespace webservice
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the      interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        List<Song> getAllSong();
    }
}
```

The result is that the WCF project does not return a list of Songs. But I've tested separately in project A and it returns the true data (a list of Songs)

I don't know how to use WCF to get data from another project in the same solution. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not return a list of Songs'? have you marked Song as a data contract with data members?

Comment: Hi devdigital, "does not return a list of Songs" means that it returns a list of Songs with length = 0;

I did not mark Song as a data contract because I think not redefine the Song class. But how to define it if must be like this?

Comment: Can you debug the correct connection string is used in whichever project invokes the WCF service? What happens if you return a hard coded list of songs from Service1?

Comment: I'm sure that the database is OK, because I've tested separately the funtion getAllSong() in project A and it returns the true data (a list of songs)

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how you've tested that, and how you're now invoking your WCF service. Presumably more than one .config file is involved.

Comment: I've tested by debuging. And I'm invoking by WCF Test Client untility. You can see the image I updated in my topic.

Comment: As I say, what happens if Service1 returns a hard coded list? Have you got the appropriate connection string in the correct .config file? Check each project.

Comment: I have added the connection string into the .config file of project B. In debug, it returns list of songs correctly. But when invoking by WCF Client, error occurred. It seems the WCF does not know the return object, because it's the business object, not data transfer object. I don't know how to convert business object to DTO.

Comment: See my first comment - have you marked Song as a data contract with data members. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. Finally, I have found the solution: that is use Omu.ValueInjecter to convert Business Object to Data Transfer Object.

Answer (score 0):

My problem have solved! Thank you devdigital for answering me.
The solution is that I use an adapter to convert business object to data transfer object. Other people have the same issue as me can go to this link: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/
to download the Omu.ValueInjecter dll.

After adding this dll file above, use this two functions to convert BO to DTO:

```
    public T ConvertObjType<T>(object obj)
    {
        T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        if (obj != null)
            StaticValueInjecter.InjectFrom((object)instance, new object[1]
    {
      obj
    });
        return instance;
    }
    public List<T> ConvertListObjType<G, T>(List<G> listObj)
    {
        if (listObj == null || listObj.Count == 0)
            return (List<T>)null;
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        typeof(T).GetProperties();
        listObj[0].GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (G g in listObj)
        {
            object obj = (object)g;
            T instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            StaticValueInjecter.InjectFrom((object)instance, new object[1]
    {
      obj
    });
            list.Add(instance);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I hope this help you out.